# Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one and already error when create any project

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

There are many answers on this question on this site but i think non of them are work with me

and here's errors:

```
[2015-06-13 19:37:02 - appcompat_v7] Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one.
[2015-06-13 19:37:02 - appcompat_v7] Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one.
[2015-06-13 19:47:07 - appcompat_v7] Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one.
[2015-06-13 19:59:00 - Moving] Eclipse\Moving\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2015-06-13 19:59:00 - Moving] Eclipse\Moving\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
Eclipse\Moving\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2015-06-13 19:59:06 - Moving] Eclipse\Moving\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2015-06-13 19:59:06 - Moving] Eclipse\Moving\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2015-06-13 19:59:06 - Moving] Eclipse\Moving\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2015-06-13 19:59:12 - Moving] Eclipse\Moving\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2015-06-13 19:59:12 - Moving] Eclipse\Moving\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2015-06-13 19:59:12 - Moving] Eclipse\Moving\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import appcompat
1.File->Import (android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7). Choose "appcompat"

2.Project-> properties->Android. In the section library "Add" and choose "appCompat" and also select build target to API 21.

Just clean your project after that

Comment: it doesn't work because the last version of Eclipse has not this steps of import can U  help me with another solution??

Comment: which version of  eclipse are you using?